# How can I use JavaScript to show or hide an image in MVC ASP.NET?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am currently working on a view where I have a list of objects. These objects contain images as one of their attributes. I would like to list out the the objects, but not show the images until the user desires. To do this I would like a button next to the description of each model. When the user clicks the button the image will appear.

My view code:

```
@{int i = 1;}
    @foreach (var r in Model.TestInputs)
    {
        <dd>
            @i) @r.InputValue
            @if (r.Image != null)
            {
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-default; showButton" value="Show Image" />
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-default; hideButton" value="Hide Image" style="display:none;" />
                <div class="image" style="display:none;">
                    <img src="@Model.InputImageStrings[i-1]" height="400" />
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('.showButton').eq(@i-1).on("click", function () {
                        $(this).eq(@i-1).hide();
                        $('.image').eq(@i-1).show();
                        $('.hideButton').eq(@i-1).show();
                    })
                    $('.hideButton').eq(@i-1).on("click", function () {
                        $(this).eq(@i-1).hide();
                        $('.image').eq(@i-1).hide();
                        $('.showButton').eq(@i-1).show();
                    })
                </script>
                <br />
                <br />
            }
        </dd>
            i++;
    }
```

This works perfectly for the first element in the list. The first button in the list will show the image for the first object in the list, but none of the other buttons do anything.

In a test to ensure that the images are there, I removed the .eq(@i-1) from the $('.image') and when I clicked the first button in the list all images were shown. Therefore, my conclusion is that for some reason all of the buttons except for the first one are not triggering the JavaScript.

If anyone has any suggestions or understands what I am doing wrong I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Your code adds javascript events for each button on each iteration of the loop. You don't want this. Instead, add a script tag at the bottom of your view and wrap the two click event handlers in a document ready function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JQuery Index](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

```
$('.showButton').on("click", function () {
    var i = $('.showButton').index(this);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I am fairly new JQuery, but why does this method of indexing work and the other didn't?

Comment: May be, with document ready wrapper this code would be work. But bad practice, i think write js in for circle.